# Check if the name of each column in dataframe contains a substring and change data type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of substrings and I want to check what columns in my data frame contains any of those substrings so I can change their data types.

For instance, if "Amount" is a substring in the list, then the columns with the names Cred_Amount, Amount_123, *Amount* should have their data types changed to int.

```
lst = ["Amount", "ID"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID_Loan': [2199, 3994, 8499, 74889, 83479],'Loan_Amount': ['100', '122', '222', '350', '300'],'Team': ['Boston', 'Boston', 'Boston', 'Chele', 'Barse'],'CreditAmount': [89, 79, 113, 78, 84],'College': ['MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'Stanford', 'Stanford'],'ID_Num': [99999, 99994, 89999, 78889, 87779]})

df
   ID_Loan Loan_Amount    Team  CreditAmount   College  ID_Num
0     2199         100  Boston            89       MIT   99999
1     3994         122  Boston            79       MIT   99994
2     8499         222  Boston           113       MIT   89999
3    74889         350   Chele            78  Stanford   78889
4    83479         300   Barse            84  Stanford   87779
```

I expected that the 1st, 2nd, 4th, and 6th columns be changed to int data type

Comment: Please be cognizant of code formatting in your post, and don't use `list` to name variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` to select and convert using `astype`:

```
u = df.filter(regex='|'.join(lst))
df[u.columns] = u.astype(int)

df.dtypes

ID_Loan          int64
Loan_Amount      int64
Team            object
CreditAmount     int64
College         object
ID_Num           int64
dtype: object
```

P.S, I've renamed your column list to `lst` because using `list` shadows the builtin which is bad practice.

---

Another option is using `str.contains` to get a mask and slice with `loc`:

```
m =  df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(lst))
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:,m].astype(int)

df.dtypes

ID_Loan          int64
Loan_Amount      int64
Team            object
CreditAmount     int64
College         object
ID_Num           int64
dtype: object
```

---

Finally, you can also use `astype` with a dictionary to selectively convert some columns, but return the whole DataFrame.

```
df = df.astype(
    dict.fromkeys(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(lst))], 'int'))

df.dtypes

ID_Loan          int64
Loan_Amount      int64
Team            object
CreditAmount     int64
College         object
ID_Num           int64
dtype: object
```